# Matrices as linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

I am reading a proof which claims:

> A matrix of $m\times n$ is a linear transformation from $m$
>   vector-space to $n$ vector-space, And therefore, by the dimension theorem: $m = \dim\ker A + \dim\Im A$

Isn't it the opposite?

For example: $A\in M_{4\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Which book is this? Does it, by any chance, use right multiplication by the matrix?

Comment: It is the opposite, as you say: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearTransformation.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix and http://math.kennesaw.edu/~sellerme/sfehtml/classes/math3260/m3260sp03sec19notes.pdf

Comment: $m$ denotes the rows and $n$ the columns. So you are right, it can be viewn as a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Dimension theorem holds, what you were assuming $n=\dim \ker + \dim \Im$. But the author obviously has the other convention, which changes the rows and columns. Therefore his statement is true. Of course you can view the same matrix as a map in either direction, by using either transposition or left instead right multiplication --- dimension theorem still holds.

Comment: I'm used to right multiplication. It is weird for me that the author (Actually it's a suggested proof for an exam) used the opposite convention. It's confusing -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us take an example:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \color{blue}1& \color{red}2 & \color{green}3 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \color{blue}{10} \\ \color{red}{20} \\ \color{green}{30}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}1 \cdot \color{blue}{10} + \color{red}2\cdot \color{red}{20} +\color{green}3 \cdot \color{green}{30} \\ 380\end{pmatrix} $$
but
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \color{blue}1& \color{red}2 & \color{green}3 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \color{blue}{10} \\ \color{red}{20} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}1 \cdot \color{blue}{10} + \color{red}2\cdot \color{red}{20} +\color{green}3 \cdot \color{green}{ ? } \\ ?\end{pmatrix} $$
seems to be harder to compute. So, if $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is set the set of matrices with $m$ rows and $n$ columns then for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $Ax \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: your answer is useless if you don't specify what $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ means. because for me your statement is obviously wrong.